# Why would my request latency be higher if excluding webfilters in the calculation? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, metrics, latency

I created 2 latency metrics: one is pre-filter and the other is post-filter.

The pre-filter one is a WebFilter that has the highest precedence and should run before any other WebFilter

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class PreFilterEndpointLatencyWebFilter implements WebFilter {
}
```

The post-filter one is a WebFilter that has the lowest precedence and should run after all other WebFilters

```
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class PostFilterEndpointLatencyWebFilter implements WebFilter {
}
```

To calculate the latency, both filters use the same piece of code:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
  final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  return chain
      .filter(exchange)
      .doOnTerminate(
          () -> {
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            latencyMetric.record(duration);
          });
}
```

My latency metric is a custom class built on top of Micrometer's `DistributionSummary` but don't think that's the issue here.

What I'm seeing is that there are times when the post-filter latency spikes while the pre-filter latency does not. I would assume that the pre-filter would always show a slightly higher latency than the post-filter one.

What's wrong with my code (or assumption)?

**Edit**
I just want to emphasize that I'd like a review of my code only since we're in the stackoverflow forum. If you think there are other factors, I appreciate you pointing them out, but I would probably address those on a more appropriate stack exchange forum with relevant info there

Comment: you are assuming that we can answer this, when the sample is way to small. Try it out on 10 000 different computers, with 100 different hardware setups then we can maybe start discussing assumptions. The problem with your assumption, is that your sample size is way way waaaay to small to make any assumptions at all. If you wish to persu this, i would suggest you start profiling all the functions, and not just your code, all the code, in the framework too, over 1000s and 1000s of requests.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but I just wanted to confirm that I didn't make any mistakes in the code I posted. I don't think it's data sampling at the moment since this is averaged over 10000s of requests, and it's why I did not provide that data